# glActiveTexutre and GL_TEXTURE0 not working, both undeclared identifiers

Tags: c++, opengl, header, identifier

So I recently picked up C++ again, only to have it throw all kinds of errors at me upon build. I included gl.h, glu.h, and the associated libraries, but Visual Studio tells me that glActiveTexture and GL_TEXTURE0 are not identifiers. Is something wrong with my gl headers? Any help would be great.

```
void setupCubeMap(GLuint& texture)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These functions and enums are not part of the GL1.1 that is part of the the  Windows API. You could either use a [current version of`glext.h`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glext.h) and manually load the function pointers via [`wglGetProcAddress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or use [some helper library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/), which handle all this cross-platform and without much hassle.

Comment: @SniGuy: No. Never use the old GLUT. If you want GLUT, use FreeGLUT.

Comment: GLUT has been abandoned since 1998. It is not maintained any more, so there are tons of issues. The FreeGLUT project is alive and kicking.